# How can i write logs in dajngorestframework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to add loggers when exception occurs , with request and response. I am using Modelserializer and genericviews. how can i write the logs in this.

Comment: Check this: https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Comment: Do you want to log in DB or file?